# BeautifulSoup Loop not returned in Sequence

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The Result returned is not in sequence , I need the result to be returned in sequence.

Trying to record Rankings.

```
def parse(self, response):
    sourceHtml = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
    soup = sourceHtml.find("dl", {"id": "resultList"})
    for link in soup.find_all('dd'):
        print(link.get('code'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the printed "codes" in a list, just use a ["list comprehension"](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def parse(self, response):
    sourceHtml = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
    soup = sourceHtml.find("dl", {"id": "resultList"})
    return [link.get('code') for link in soup.find_all('dd')]
```

You can also improve the way you locate the elements and use a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
def parse(self, response):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
    return [link.get('code') for link in soup.select('dl#resultList dd')]
```

It is also a good idea to [provide an underlying parser explicitly](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, "html.parser")
# or soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, "html5lib")
# or soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, "lxml")
```